# Conda environment not deactivated after switch environments

Tags: conda

I don't know if other people has the same issue.

I have two environment, say A, B.

When I switch from A to B, I simply prompt

```
conda activate B
```

I assume this automatically deactivate A, but I can still use packages installed in A. Besides, I fall back to A when I deactivate B.

It is bizarre to me because the two environments shouldn't see each other.

Is this normal ?

Comment: Why do you think you can still use packages installed in A? How did you create the two environments?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help.
[link to conda managing environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment)